# Select the information displayed by tooltips on Google Charts in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization

I have made a Scatter Chart with **React** but I want to change the data showed in the tooltip. The Scatter Chart displays the following array, so I can't just add a new column like this ( `{ role: "tooltip", type: "string", p: { html: true } )`:

```
0: (10) ["Day", {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
1: (10) ["03", null, null, null, null, 50, null, null, null, null]
2: (10) ["04", null, null, null, 40, null, null, null, null, null]
3: (10) ["05", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

The 0 position contains this info:

```
0: "Day"
1: {type: "number", label: "Consult"}
2: {type: "number", label: "Medication"}
3: {type: "number", label: "Rescue"}
4: {type: "number", label: "Urgency"}
5: {type: "number", label: "Others"}
6: {type: "number", label: "Event"}
7: {type: "number", label: "Symptom"}
8: {type: "number", label: "High consumption"}
9: {type: "number", label: "Crisis"}
```

Each one of this "vital events" have a value, so it can be displayed on the graph, that looks like this:
[image: Graph image]

And the tooltips are displayed like this:

[image: Graph tooltips]

The problem is that I would like to control the info in the tooltip, or at least **remove** the 'vital event' **value** (in the image is 40, the corresponding value for Urgencia ('Urgency'), so it will display something like: Urgencia 04.

This is also the chart code:

```
                   <Chart
                    chartType="ScatterChart"
                    loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                    data={ data}
                    options={{
                        colors: pointColors,
                        width: chartWidth ,     
                        height: 160,
                        position:true, 
                        backgroundColor:{
                            strokeWidth:0
                        },
                        chartArea: {
                            top: 10,
                            height: height,
                            width:'85%',
                            right: 0, 
                            left: 40,                    
                        },
                        isStacked: stacked,
                        tooltipFontSize: 15,
                        legend: { position: 'none', fontSize:13, italic: false },
                        vAxis: {
                             gridlines: {
                                color: 'transparent',
                            }, 
                            ticks: ticks, 
                            titleTextStyle: { 
                                fontSize:5,
                                italic: false,
                            },
                            textStyle:{
                                fontSize: 5
                            }
                          },
                        hAxis:{
                            minValue: 0,  
                            slantedText: false,
                            textStyle: {
                                fontSize: 12
                            }
                        },
                        annotations:{
                            textStyle: {
                                fontName: 'Times-Roman',
                                fontSize: 13,
                                bold: true,
                                italic: false,
                    
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                    rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}  
                   />
```

Comment: in order to control the tooltip, you will need to add a tooltip column, after each series column. as you have indicated in the post. there really isn't another option. are you using the routine to build the data developed in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577933/5090771)? if so, we can modify that routine to add the tooltip columns...

Comment: I'm using the React way, with the Chart component, so I'm guessing If I want to do it, I have to change to pure JavaScript. But thank you very much @WhiteHat!

Comment: I usually use react-google-charts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts), it's important to go through the official documentation on Google (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content), especially on tooltips.